# Null problem when (de)serializing multiple objects with json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

**[SOLVED]** applied given solution, works fine!

Aim of the program: Save/reload previous data when user opens and closes the program.

I used to (de)serialize **successfully** with **one object**(`obj`), now I have two different objects of different classes.

I tried to combine them by looking at other posts; I put them in object array and give that object array when (de)serializing as parameter.

> I do initialize for example like this; `obj.flag1 = true;` before
>   calling `serialize()` in other methods.(I didn't put them for simplicity since I already stated the functionality of methods)

It says objects are null, but logically if obj2 and obj were null, it should have given the error for obj standalone. It won't read empty file I handled it. The moment I tried to combine two object it started to give me null error for both of them. I am about to rip my hair, can someone please help?

```
 [Serializable]
    public partial class UI : Form
    {
        FlagClass obj;
        CurrentAmplitude obj2;

        object[] seri_obj;//combine multiple objects

        //deserialization is performed in constructor
        public UI()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            seri_obj = new object[] { obj, obj2 };

            input += ".txt";

            //default path + new filename
            path_combined = Path.Combine(root, input);

            //it won't try to read empty file
            if (!File.Exists(path_combined))
            {

                using (var stream = File.Create(path_combined))
                {

                }

            }
            else //already have that file,so when user opens the program, data is loaded from file
            {
                //read booleans and inetegres

                string json2 = File.ReadAllText(path_combined);
                string FormattedJson = FormatJson(json2);
                seri_obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(FormattedJson);

            }
        }


        private static string FormatJson(string json)
        {
            dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Formatting.Indented);
        }

        //I do serialization here
        void Serialize()
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(seri_obj, Formatting.Indented);
            File.WriteAllText(path_combined, json);

        }
```

> String values are in this class via "obj2"

```
[Serializable]
    class CurrentAmplitude
    {
    //this class has the string values
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value1")]
        public int value1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value2")]
        public string value2 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value3")]
        public string value3 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value4")]
        public string value4 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value5")]
        public string value5 { get; set; }


        public CurrentAmplitude(){

        }
    }
```

> Boolean values are in this class via "obj"

```
[Serializable]
    class FlagClass
    {
    //this class has the boolean values
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "flag1")]
        public bool flag1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "flag2")]
        public bool flag2 { get; set; }

        public FlagClass()
        { 

        }

    }
```

[image: warning of null objects]

Comment: Why are you deserializing then serializing then deserializing the same json over and over ?

Comment: @PommeDeTerre because when user open and close this program data should be saved where it left off, meaning variables are fetched how it is initialized previously

Comment: Ok, but when the file exists you read it into json2, then pass it to FormatJson where you deserialize it and then serialize it again only to have it finally deserialized into seri_obj. Why don'you simply write seri_obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(json2);?

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli it is just for formatting to display json objects, but even I don't use it and simply apply yours, the objects look still null

Comment: I see the purpose of your FormatJson method and it certainly is not the cause of your issue, but using it that way is useless, resource consuming, and makes your code more difficult to understand.

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli Yes, you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you are deserializing:-

```
seri_obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(FormattedJson);
```

You are asking the deserializer to return an array raw objects, which will result in an array of `JObject` types, not your `FlagClass` and `CurrentAmplitude` types.

You're also setting `seri_obj`, but never assigning the values in `seri_obj` to your `obj` or `obj2` variables, which is why the compiler is warning you.

You would be better off having an umbrella configuration class like this:-

```
class Configuration
{
    public Flag { get; set; } = new FlagClass();

    public CurrentAmplitude { get; set; } = new CurrentAmplitude();
}
```

Then just deserialize/serialize an instance of your `Configuration` class when you want to load/save...

```
// create config object if new
var config = new Configuration();

// to save
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(config);

// to load
var config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(json);

// get/set config values
config.Flag.flag2 = false;
```

Here is a more complete example:-

```
void Main()
{
    // create a new blank configuration
    Configuration config = new Configuration();

    // make changes to the configuration
    config.CurrentAmplitude.value1 = 123;
    config.CurrentAmplitude.value2 = "Hello";
    config.FlagClass.flag1 = false;
    config.FlagClass.flag2 = true;

    // serialize configuration to a string in order to save to a file
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(config);

    // reload config from saved string
    config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(json);

    // should print "Hello"
    Console.WriteLine(config.CurrentAmplitude.value2);
}

class Configuration
{
    public CurrentAmplitude CurrentAmplitude { get; set; } = new CurrentAmplitude();

    public FlagClass FlagClass { get; set; } = new FlagClass();
}

class CurrentAmplitude
{
    public int value1 { get; set; }

    public string value2 { get; set; }

    public string value3 { get; set; }

    public string value4 { get; set; }

    public string value5 { get; set; }
}

class FlagClass
{
    public bool flag1 { get; set; }

    public bool flag2 { get; set; }
}
```

Pre C# 6, your config class would look like this:-

```
class Configuration
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        CurrentAmplitude = new CurrentAmplitude();
        FlagClass = new FlagClass();
    }

    public CurrentAmplitude CurrentAmplitude { get; set; }

    public FlagClass FlagClass { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but to make other classes visible to `UI` I used `FlagClass obj` and `CurrentAmplitude obj2`, to apply your solution do I have to delete them? 43 methods are using obj, and also I can not put `Configuration` class in same namespace, it says you can not use `new` like that etc.

Comment: Why is adding Configuration not feasible? Anyway you don't have to delete obj and obj1 (BTW these are really bad names), simply add obj = config.Flag; and obj2 = config.CurrentAmplitude; after ahving deserialized Configuration.

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli btw this config class syntax gives error, do you mean public `CurrentAmplitude obj { get; set; } = new CurrentAmplitude();`

Comment: Using the example in my answer, you should only ever need to have a reference to the `Configuration` class... you can always access the properties and (sub)classes in the configuration class from there. You would get rid of `obj` and `obj2` and just have a reference to the `config` variable that you either create (for a fresh intall) or deserialize (when loading from a saved file)

Comment: @Selen, I've just added some code that should (hopefully) help.

Comment: @Aleks I did exactly the same but your solution's syntax gives problem in visual studio I edit my post, upload the picture can you check again please ?

Comment: @Selen what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @Aleks I use Visual Studio 2019

Comment: @Selen try the edited `Configuration` class at the end of my updated answer.

Comment: @Selen Oh, I see the issue now, you have `public CurrentAmplitude { get; set; }` instead of `public CurrentAmplitude CurrentAmplitude { get; set; }`... it's missing the property name